# web site different rendering on remote an local url in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, html-rendering

I'm developing my wedding's website, and I have a problem I really don't understand: when I browse it on my local machine the site is rendered correctly, but if I browse the site remotely there is a section shown in a wrong way. In order to be sure about the files correctness I just removed on ftp all the site's files and re-uploaded them from scratch. Same problem. It happens on safari only, on all the other browsers the site is rendered fine

this is how I see the site locally

[image]

this is how I see the same file remotely

How can it be possible?

For anyone who want to help the link to the site is http://silviaesimone.com

thank you

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I'm working on Win8 and tried with all browser (safari, FF, IE, chrome). Is it possible to be a cache problem?

Comment: I don't think so, also with private browsing the problem still remains :(  thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The server is using the wrong MIME type for the Bebas Neue font. It sends the font as `text/plain` which, apparently, Safari can't handle.

Solution: make sure that files with extension .otf are served with the correct MIME type, which is `font/opentype`.

(It depends on the kind of server how you need to do that; see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for IIS or [here](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/adding-mime-types/) for Apache).